# Can we expect that $ \int_{\mathbb T} \left| \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} e^{-in^{r}} e^{inx} \right| dx $ is finite for some $r>0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\mathbb T$ denotes the torus and $r>0.$

> My Question is: Can we expect  that 
>   $$ \int_{\mathbb T= [0, 2\pi)} \left| \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} e^{-in^{r}} e^{inx} \right|  dx $$
>   is finite for some $r>0$? If so, how to justify or any known  referneces (approach)  to treat the problem?

Edit: $\mathbb T =\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}$ simply circle group.

Comment: So, the torus, as in the Cartesian product $S^1\times S^1$, with $S^1$ being the unit circle? How would you even define the exponential function of points on a torus?

Comment: $\mathbb T =\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}$ simply circle group.

Comment: So, if $x \in \mathbb T$, then then for most $x$, we have $e^{ix} \not\in \mathbb T$ ??

Comment: $\mathbb T=[0,2 \pi)$ measure theoretically  when we consider the integration.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression as written is simply undefined.  All terms in your sum have absolute value $1$, so the sum diverges.

It is possible, however, that some [summability method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Summability_methods) for divergent series could be used to make sense of it.

Comment: That's what I thought at first.  But he said $\mathbb T =\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}$, so if $x \in \mathbb T$ we do not have $e^{ix} \in \mathbb T$.  In any case, the question needs explanation.